# Concurrent Threads for Incoming & Outgoing Bluetooth Connections

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, bluetooth

There are multiple concurrent threads

Some of them are trying to connect to a slave device by creating a `BluetoothSocket` using `BluetoothDevice`, through device mac-address. These threads the use socket.connect, and there is a delay of 2 seconds in between each run.

Concurrently, other threads trying to establish an incoming connection, by creating a `BluetoothServerSocket` through `BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommusingServiceRecord` using a Universal UUID.

The point is if these threads are not concurrent then each of them works fine, but in case they are running parallel, the incoming connections are never recieved.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Bt discovery mode can't coexist with send&receive mode. So you can't put your device to listen for connections and at the same time send and receive data from other devices.
Edited: You can move from one state to another, but can't stay in both at the same time.

Comment: Looks like that only. And, FYI BT Discovery Mode is turned off after devices are paired.

Comment: Maybe the reason, But i often get the Master devices connected while one slave device connection thread is running back to back. Is this documented somewhere like Bluetooth SIG, So that get some more insights.